# Solving SDP problems with pyomo and Mosek

Tags: pyomo, sdp, mosek

The output of my solver gives the following error>>

Error: rescode.err_qcon_upper_triangle(1417): Only elements in the lower triangle of the quadratic terms should be specified. The element q[1,12] is in the upper triangle of 0th constraint is specified.

Any idea on how I can go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: This sounds like it could potentially be a bug in Pyomo’s interface to Mosek. It would be a good idea to open an issue on Pyomo’s Github page, including with it a small example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Many thanks. On another note, how would one go about declaring an nxn sdp variable matrix in pyomo + imposing the positive semidefinite condition

Comment: @ABB  I don't think pyomo supports sdp  variables at the moment. In any case the pyomo-mosek interface certainly does not.

Comment: Many thanks @MichalAdamaszek; Do you have a recommendation on a pyomo-'some solver' interface that supports sdp variables? Or is Matlab the only way to go here?

Comment: @ABB I would use cvxpy+mosek for sdp variables. I don't think pyomo supports them at all but maybe someone who knows pyomo better can correct me.

Comment: Many thanks. cvxpy+mosek works perfectly.